# Anchor tag helper including page in querystring instead (?page=)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a Razor Page which includes an anchor tag on a navigation bar ViewComponent like so:

```html
<a asp-page="/Settings">Settings</a>
```

My understanding is that this should navigate to my 'Settings' Razor page, right? (e.g. Settings/Index.cshtml).

When the page loads, the HTML renders as:

```html
<a href="/?page=%2FSettings">Settings</a>
```

How is this possible?

According to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1#asp-page), I'm doing the correct thing here.

My Startup configures the endpoints as follows:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the path to the page is `/Settings/Index`, not just `/Settings`, so you need to use that:

```html
<a asp-page="/Settings/Index">Settings</a>
```

In the example from the docs, the page is just `/Attendee`, because it's referring to `Attendee.cshtml` and not `Attendee/Index.cshtml`.